# Using msbuild to publish my sln file

Tags: msbuild-task

My requirement is as below

Execute MSBuild on a sln file configured to publish as a website, and then copy the precompiled website files to a webserver ( am using cc.net )

When I try the following cmd on msbuild,

**msbuild abc.sln /t:publish /p:Configuration=Release**

I get the following error

**Web projects do not support the "Publish" target**

I do not have 'csproj' file in my website and need to work on 'sln' file to publish..

Can you kindly assist

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'Web Deployment Projects' are what you are looking for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336619.aspx